# ASP.NET MVC dynamic route that is same as default controller/action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need routes to match sometimes controllers, and sometimes - database values. Here's an example:

/controller/action?id=test - this is the default {controller}/{action} route

/name/type?flag=test - this is my custom {dbvalue}/{dbvalue} route

As you can see, the two routes are the same. But if {controller} or {action} is a specific value (only known at runtime because it depends on DB) - I need the route to match my other route (i.e. /specificcontroller/handleall(string name, string type) action).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the answer would be to implement IRouteConstraint to exclude DB values from the {controller} values accepted in the default route.

E.g.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },  // Parameter defaults
            new { controller = new ExcludeValuesConstraint("dbvalue1", "dbvalue2") }
        );
```

Of course excluded values have to be dynamic.

The trick was not to add constraints to my route, but to exclude the values from the default route.

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested yet but just an idea:

Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute("DbRoute", "{dbValue1}/{dbValue2}", new {controller = "RouteController", action = "Index"});
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

then in method action `Index()` inside class `RouteController`, you check for the `dbValue1` and `dbValue2`. If not match, you can use `RedirectToRoute("Default", ...)` method.

By this way, any request will match `DbRoute` first and `RouteController` will check for the db value, if not match simply forward the route to the `Default` and render the view based on **controller/action**.